# NoMethodError in MoviesController#upvote

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project, and for the life of me, I'm not sure what's going on. My code was working earlier, now I'm getting

```
NoMethodError in MoviesController#upvote
```

When I try and vote on a certain movie, here is my "movie_controller.rb"

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
  before_action :authenticate_user! 


  # GET /movies
  # GET /movies.json
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  # GET /movies/1
  # GET /movies/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /movies/new
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  # GET /movies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /movies
  # POST /movies.json
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /movies/1
  # DELETE /movies/1.json
  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def upvote
    @movie.upvote_from current_user 
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  def downvote
    @movie.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  private
    def set_movie 
      @movies = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    end 


    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :image)
    end
end
```

In particular it's saying there's a problem with is line:

```
private
    def set_movie 
      @movies = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I'll also attach my routes for good measure. Thank you guys.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
    root 'home#index'

    resources :movies do

    put "like", to: "movies#upvote"
    put "unlike", to: "movies#downvote"
  end
end
```

Comment: would you add the full stack of the error?

Comment: Hey@geekazoid,  here you go `undefined method upvote_from' for nil:NilClass
              
  
    def upvote
    @movie.upvote_from current_user 
    redirect_to movies_path
  end`

Comment: That's not the full stack trace of the error, but now I get the idea. I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting a `@movies` variable instead of `@movie`. That's why you are getting a `undefined method upvote_from' for nil:NilClass def upvote @movie.upvote_from`

Change this part of the code

```
private
def set_movie 
  @movies = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

to this

```
private
def set_movie 
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: @MontanaMendy please mark the answer as correct if so. You are welcome.